# AWS Route 53 Connected to S3 Status Web Host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

So, I've created a website xxxxxxx.com (removing from post)
I registered it with Route 53.
[Registered Domain - Established Hosted Zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBgVr.png)

Established 2 Record Sets one of xxxxxxxx.com and one for [www.xxxxxx.com](http://www.xxxxxx.com)
[Record Set Details for one of the paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qspwf.png)

But when I go to ping [www.xxxxxxxx.com](http://www.xxxxxxxx.com) or xxxxxxxx.com - I don't get a response.
When I go to a DNS checker site - it fails all DNS servers.

I've been all over the place trying to get this to work, concerningly, it did work at one time, but then failed. I have deleted the hosted zone twice and rebuilt it. I have NOT touched the named servers.

S3:
setup 2 buckets, named appropriately. xxxxxxxx.com and [www.xxxxxxxx.com](http://www.xxxxxxxx.com)
Both have two files on them. Block public is unchecked.
Static Web hosting is enabled.
Selected both files and set to Actions --> Make Public

Testing on their own with these addresses:
**edited - I had to remove the direct S3 Web hosting as once posted here they got hammered with hits.

I did try one other thing:
Route 53 --> Traffic Policies --> Create Traffic Policy -->
DNS Type a: IP address in IPv4 format to Endpoint Type S3 website endpoint Value xxxxxxxx.com.s3-website-us-east-2....

This does not appear to have rectified the situation, unfortunately. And they want to charge $10 a month to direct it with www. prefix - which doesn't make any kind of sense, so I didn't do that.

Any advice or help that can be rendered would be helpful! I've covered most of the ground with Amazon and videos setting up domain to S3 to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Something seems off with your DNS records: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/fojsan.com

Domain registered 2 days ago, should have NS listed in all regions. Leave the S3 for the time being and focus here. If DNS record can not resolve , S3 will not work.

Make sure that DNS entry for NS (name Servers) is set to:

```
ns-1145.awsdns-15.org.
ns-1694.awsdns-19.co.uk.
ns-20.awsdns-02.com. 
ns-576.awsdns-08.net.
```

It looks like it might have been removed and are expiring.

Comment: I'll check it out. After posting my S3 links here - they got hammered with hits. So I had to make them private or exceed my free tier.

Comment: From Amazon - Registered Domains Screen - Name Servers: The name servers that respond to DNS queries for this domain.
ns-1145.awsdns-15.org
ns-1694.awsdns-19.co.uk
ns-576.awsdns-08.net
ns-20.awsdns-02.com

Comment: Something is still not right with these DNS entries and propagation. Please check for NS entries on https://www.whatsmydns.net/

Comment: OK, you got me most of the way there. https://cloudconfusing.com/2019/07/24/how-to-restore-your-original-amazon-route-53-name-servers/ - shows how to get your correct DNS. and then I went to the Domain and changed the name servers and I can ping at least now.

Comment: Good to hear it.